# DISM throws error with HRESULT=80310000

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8.1, winpe, dism

Got an error out of DISM when attempting to capture Surface Pro 3's existing image. I boot to WinPE via USB flash drive fine. I attached a second USB drive (Drive E:) AFTER WinPE boot, and check that I can navigate to it. I can, so I return back to the WinPE drive and then execute the command:

```
Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:E:\My_Win81.wim /CaptureDir:C:\ /Name:"July2015"
```

Dism errors out. Examination of the Dism log only reveals this one line:

```
wimmanager processed the command line but failed hresult=80310000
```

I've searched several sources and come up empty handed - Microsoft doesn't have any documentation that I've found on this DISM error, so I'm here asking if anyone's run into this before and what, if anything was your solution / workaround.

Note: Thinking it might have something to do with the second drive, I tried saving to the initial WinPE USB drive; same exact result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geeze. Nevermind - my brain is running on only one cup of coffee this morning. I need to shutdown BitLocker first before capturing an image.

Comment: this is correct: **80310000 = FVE_E_LOCKED_VOLUME** (*This drive is locked by BitLocker Drive Encryption. You must unlock this drive from Control Panel*)

Comment: bitlocker is (as intended) a pain. thanks for explaining this error!